# Comic where Teenage Male gains powers from a dying Alien, takes the form of a tattoo that can be moved around body

Tags: story-identification, comics, powers

I have been searching this for a while with no luck — so forgive the spotty recollection. I am looking for a Western (American?) comic book I read in the '90s as a child.

A teenage boy finds a crash landed ship. The dying alien transfers powers to him, which is marked by a tattoo that the boy can move around his body (using his willpower). However, I forget what the actual powers were. Any help would be great; this has been bugging me for ages.

Comment: The premise of dying alien giving away a power sounds like Abin Sur landing on Earth and Hal Jordan receiving the Green Lantern ring (though in this case, it's not supposed to be a ring but a tattoo).

Comment: Sadly that's not the one - turns out it was Star Brand as Happy Robot suggested

Answer (score 4):

Possibly Marvel's Star Brand

From Wikipedia:
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Brand

The original Star Brand is a black star-shaped tattoo-like mark that first appeared in the comic book series Star Brand, published by Marvel Comics as a part of its New Universe imprint from 1986 to 1989

The Old Man is the first known wielder of the brand. Originally he claimed to be an alien warrior.

The initial main character is not a teenager: He is a car mechanic from Pittsburgh who receives the Star Brand from the Old Man in the woods, however other people have used the star brand.

Comment: That's the one! Thanks so much, reading it now and on a huge nostalgia trip, thanks again!